# Merging Directories Based on their Suffix

Tags: fedora, directory-structure, merge

I have a directory structure produced during archiving. The archiving system can't be changed. Whenever a duplicate directory occurs the archiver appends an integer suffix to the directory name. My goal is to collapse these so that there is only one directory per name (no suffixes) and sub-directories are merged.

```
# Current Structure
/
+-- Folder_Name/
    +-- 20170913/
        +-- File One
+-- Folder_Name_1/
    +-- 20170913/
        +-- File One
        +-- File Two
+-- Folder_Name_2/
    +-- 20170915/
        +-- File Three
+-- Folder_Name_3/
    +-- 20170918/
        +-- File Four

# What I would like to achieve
/
+-- Folder_Name/
    +-- 20170913/
        +-- File One
        +-- File Two
    +-- 20170915/
        +-- File Three
    +-- 20170918/
        +-- File Four
```

Lots of folders are created during archiving (it is an ultrasound machine saving a monthly backup of all images) and there are often duplicates produced. At the same time I am using ImageMagick to convert the bitmap files to png in order to keep file sizes down.

I have tried to do this with `rsync` using the --remove-source-files option, but I haven't been able to find a way to match these directories for `rsync`  (I don't think it supports regex). I then tried to use `find` to pipe the output into `rsync` but can't work out a) the regex that would achieve that; and b) how to provide the suffixed and un-suffixed directory names. I am thinking I need to use variables for this, but am not experienced with shell scripting.

Am I taking the right approach here? If so, could someone point me to a resource or tutorial that can walk me through setting this up? If not then what tools should I be looking at using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure a simple

```
cp -R Folder_Name_*/* Folder_Name
```

will do all the merge for you. After you checked the result, you can remove the source directories.

If you have multiple folders to merge, build a `for` loop around it:

```
for folder in *_1; do
  folder="${folder%_*}"
  cp -R "$folder"_* "$folder"
  # rm -rf "$folder"_*
done
```

(`rm` commented out until verified)

Comment: Thanks for the response but it would be too time consuming to do this with each folder name that matched that pattern. Each folder name equates to a patient name (John_Doe, John_Doe_1, Jane_Smith, Jane_Smith_1, etc). There are hundreds of these.

Comment: You could add a loop to @Philippos solution. You need to select the actual names:  

`ls | grep -v "_[0-9]*$"`  

then run the command over those names:  

`for i in $( ls | grep -v "_[0-9]*$" ); do cp -R $i_*/* $i; done`

Comment: Thanks folks. Works perfectly. I've tweaked Philippos code very slightly to make the cp `cp -R "$folder"_*/. "$folder"` to make sure the `Folder_Name_*` doesn't get placed within `Folder_Name`.